# Endpoint doesn't support config request for MaxEnvelopsizekb

Tags: knife

I am trying to bootstrap a windows server 2012 and I keep getting this error.

Endpoint doesn't support config request for MaxEnvelopsizekb

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Command which I am using is:

```
knife bootstrap -o winrm IPADDRESS -x vagrant -P 'vagrant' -N node1windows -r 'recipe[newcookbook]'-VV
```

Comment: I have the same issue trying to bootstrap a windows 7 laptop. My command is: 
`knife bootstrap -o winrm fqdn.for.my.laptop -'role[dev-client]'  -U najmi   -P somepassword -N fqdn.for.my.laptop  -VVV`. 

I get error:

 `DEBUG: [WinRM] Endpoint doesn't support config request for MaxEnvelopsizekb`